How to change user language on SharePoint online user have visitors access
I am changing user language using following code in SPFx Application customizer extension.
this code workig fine when user have Edit permission but when user have visitors permission then I get unauthrize error. Please suggest me any work around.
sp.web.siteUserInfoList.items
  .getById(this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext['userId'])
  .update({
    'MUILanguages': `${selectedValue},en-US`
  })
  .then(() => {
    //console.log
    //localStorage.setItem('isFirstReload', 'true');
    if (selectedValue == "ar-AE")
      localStorage.setItem('Language', 'arabic');
    else
      localStorage.setItem('Language', 'english');
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.open(window.location.href,"_blank");
    }, 1000);
});


As visitors your users can't write to SharePoint. Thus, the update is where it gets the error.  Moving visitors to contributors should help.
